# OpenWRT - PYTHONPATH, не дает установить virtualenv

Tags: python, консоль, openwrt

Здравствуйте, 
столкнулся с такой проблемой. При попытки установки virtualenv в не стандартную директорию, возникает следующая ошибка:

```
python setup.py install --home=/root/usb/pythonMH

running install
Checking .pth file support in /root/usb/pythonMH/lib/python/
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST FAILED: /root/usb/pythonMH/lib/python/ does NOT support .pth files
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /root/usb/pythonMH/lib/python/

and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

    ':/root/usb'

Here are some of your options for correcting the problem:

* You can choose a different installation directory, i.e., one that is
  on PYTHONPATH or supports .pth files

* You can add the installation directory to the PYTHONPATH environment
  variable.  (It must then also be on PYTHONPATH whenever you run
  Python and want to use the package(s) you are installing.)

* You can set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files by
  using one of the approaches described here:

  https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#custom-installation-locations

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

прочитал разные статьи и пытался найти устранение проблемы, но не как не получается.
Прошу помочь советами.

Comment: а второе предложенное решение (о `PYTHONPATH`) чем-то не подходит? а варианты, изложенные по ссылке в третьем предложенном решении, читали?

Comment: все читал и пробывал. к сожалению результат один.

Comment: как именно пробовали? так: `PYTHONPATH=/root/usb/pythonMH/lib/python/ python setup.py install --home=/root/usb/pythonMH` ?

Comment: сейчас еще раз все перепроверил, выходит следующие.

`python setup.py install --home=/root/usb/pythonMH
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory
The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:
    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/usb/pythonMH/lib/python/test-easy-install-1321.write-test'

Comment: `
The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:
    /root/usb/pythonMH/lib/python/
This directory does not currently exist.  Please create it and try again, or
choose a different installation directory (using the -d or --install-dir
option).`

Comment: *Please create it and try again* — перевод: создайте этот каталог (`/root/usb/pythonMH/lib/python/`) и попробуйте снова. создать каталог (вместе с возможно отсутствующими промежуточными каталогами) можно так: `mkdir -p /путь/к/каталогу`.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает. Главная проблема была все же в

`PYTHONPATH=/root/usb/pythonMH/lib/python/`

Comment: оформил в виде ответа, чтобы, возможно, информация помогла кому-то ещё.

Comment: есть еще одна маленькая проблема. установил virtualenv, но при запуске `virtualenv venv` показывает следующие `-ash: virtualenv: not found
`

Comment: я так понимаю, что *virtualenv* вы как раз и устанавливали обсуждаемой командой. значит, бинарник (или скрипт?) *virtualenv*, надо думать, попал куда-то внутрь каталога `/root/usb/pythonMH`. найти можно командой `find /root/usb/pythonMH -name virtualenv`. вот с абсолютным путём его и запускайте: `/путь/к/virtualenv`. вероятно, и переменную `PYTHONPATH` перед этим надо будет экспортировать (см. в моём ответе команду `export ...`).

Comment: сделал как вы мне посоветовали: http://pastebin.com/84vgZamv
sudo или su, работать на openwrt не будет

Comment: *openwrt*, скажем так, не позиционируется для многопользовательской работы, поэтому там работа, как правило, осуществляется от пользователя *root*. вы что, под другим пользователем подключились? если нет, то разберитесь, что содержится в переменных `py_executable_base` и `full_pth` перед выполнением `os.symlink(py_executable_base, full_pth)` (из приведённого вами лога).

Comment: собственно нет, никаких других пользователей, я не использовал. сами переменные не изменял. но все же интересно, почему пишет - нет прав.

Comment: разберитесь, что содержится в переменных.

Comment: если с этим проблемы — задайте новый вопрос по данному поводу (сославшись, возможно, на этот вопрос): «питонисты» подскажут, как вывести значения переменных.

Comment: ну пока я постараюсь разобраться собственными силами, а потом посмотрим )

Comment: хинт по поводу интерфейса stackoverflow: если в эту дискуссию добавится ещё кто-нибудь, то я перестану получать уведомления, в которых явно не упомянуто моё имя (посмотрите справку справа от формы ответа).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin разобрался как запустить, но все же одна проблема есть. При запуски virtualenv venv, он устанавливает setuptools и pip, но из за того, что на openwrt достаточно мало места, примерно 16мб, из них 3 мб свободны, мне все это надо перетащить на USB... Как это сделать, прочитал туториал, но нужного не нашел.

Comment: то, что изложено в последнем комментарии, лучше задать в виде нового вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в приведённом сообщении есть рекомендация: присвоить переменной окружения `PYTHONPATH` значение `/root/usb/pythonMH/lib/python/` и повторить попытку запуска скрипта.

это можно сделать примерно таким образом:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/root/usb/pythonMH/lib/python/ python setup.py install --home=/root/usb/pythonMH
```

или двумя отдельными командами:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/root/usb/pythonMH/lib/python/
$ python setup.py install --home=/root/usb/pythonMH
```

только предварительно сто́ит убедиться, что такой каталог существует.

проще всего сразу его создать (вместе с возможно отсутствующими промежуточными каталогами). эту команду можно смело выполнить, потому что если каталог уже есть, она не сделает ничего:

```
$ mkdir -p /root/usb/pythonMH/lib/python/
```